# cakephp comet usleep blocks everything

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, comet

Below is the code that i am end up with using successful comet implementation.

```
$lastmodif = isset($this->params['form']['timestamp']) ? $this->params['form']['timestamp'] : 0;
$currentmodif = $already_updated[0]['Update']['lastmodified'];

while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif)
{
    usleep(5000000);
    clearstatcache();
    $already_updated_new = $this->Update->find('all',array
    (
        'conditions' => array
        ( 
            'Update.receiver_id' =>  $this->Auth->user('id'),
            'Update.table_name' =>  "request_responses"
        )
    ));
    $currentmodif = $already_updated_new[0]['Update']['lastmodified'];
}
```

`$already_updated[0]['Update']['lastmodified']` is the query result for get last updated timestamp of table.

In above code $lastmodif and $currentmodif is the timestamp that is being passed after every successful comet response.

But now problem is that when i am clicking on other links on same page nothing happens but after wait for so long its redirecting.

i think usleep is blocking other `HTTP` request.

i am using mysql and cakephp please guys guide me what should i do in order to solve this issue.

I have tried to flush when page is called but it shows can not modify header error as output is already sent.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? if you did, please write an answer, if you didn't, it would be useful if you provide the view code. I may be able to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've met similar situation several times. It looks like Session is blocked by your sleeping script.

**How to solve it in CakePHP:**
call `session_write_close();` at the start of your script.
There is no way to do that via Cake's Session Component or Helper
**Note**: If something inside script uses session - Cake will reopen session and hang all requests that use same session again. In this case you will need to close session before sleep or before any operations that take a lot of time to be finished

Answer (score 1):

If your script uses sessions then you could notice such behavior. PHP locks the session file until the script completes.

This means that once a script starts a session, any other script that attempts to start a session using same session id is blocked until the previous script releases the lock (or terminates).

The workaround for this is to unlock the session before any lengthy process:

- call `session_start()`
- read/write any session variables
- call `session_write_close()`
- do lengthy processing

Comment: correct i know this but i don't know how to do that in cakephp way.

Comment: I looked at the documentation but did not find any "close" method. You can call `session_write_close` yourself and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the usleep is blocking further requests. Depending on your hosting environment, you probably have a limited amount of processes available. I assume you have multiple users in your chat -> they all issue blocking processes unless none is available, that's why your other "links" timeout.

I would suggest to implement the wait on the client-browser side, eg

```
setTimeout(function() {
    fetchAndPrintTheNewChats();
}, 50000000);
```

Any approach to do this within your PHP code will result in the same problem.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i don't want suggestions, i want to use comet because if this problem solve then it will automatically solve my so many problem because other problem rely on this problem..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what version of cakephp you are using in case someone else who comes along might have a solution?

Cake has a session component: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html

and a session helper: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html